# Google Maps Custom Info Windows - Have one open and then close the other once thats open etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am struggling with this- Got a Google Map with some custom Info Windows. So on click on marker will change the information on the box on left hand side. Got the Default one displaying on load on page and needs to change when you click on the diffrent points on the map. I have France changing but you can not click on other items. Likewise with NY. Any Ideas where I am going wrong?

I have attached below my Code. Any help will be much appreciated.

Hope that helps.

```js
function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    center: {
      lat: 40.7499256,
      lng: -73.9854028
    },
    zoom: 3,
    zoomControl: false,
    panControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var img = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWM0W.png";

  var NewYork = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: mapOptions.center,
    map: map,
    icon: img
  });

  var London = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: 51.5106122,
      lng: -0.1529072
    },
    map: map,
    icon: img
  });

  var Paris = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: 48.8588589,
      lng: 2.3470599
    },
    map: map,
    icon: img
  });

  var HongKong = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: 22.2753729,
      lng: 114.1757384
    },
    map: map,
    icon: img
  });

  var markers = {
    'NewYork': NewYork,
    'London': London,
    'Paris': Paris,
    'HongKong': HongKong
  };

  NewYork.addListener('click', changeContent);
  Paris.addListener('click', changeContentTwo);


  var styles = [{
      "featureType": "water",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#d3d3d3"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "transit",
      "stylers": [{
          "color": "#808080"
        },
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "on"
        },
        {
          "color": "#b3b3b3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.local",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "on"
        },
        {
          "color": "#ffffff"
        },
        {
          "weight": 1.8
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.local",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#d7d7d7"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "on"
        },
        {
          "color": "#ebebeb"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "administrative",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#a7a7a7"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.arterial",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.arterial",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "landscape",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "on"
        },
        {
          "color": "#efefef"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#696969"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "administrative",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "on"
        },
        {
          "color": "#737373"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "labels.icon",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "labels",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.arterial",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#d6d6d6"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road",
      "elementType": "labels.icon",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    },
    {},
    {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#dadada"
      }]
    }
  ];

  map.setOptions({
    styles: styles
  });




  function changeContent() {
    $("#klk-map-content-1").fadeOut("fast", function() {
      $("#klk-map-content-2").fadeIn("slow");
    });
  }

  function changeContentTwo() {
    $("#klk-map-content-1").fadeOut("fast", function() {
      $("#klk-map-content-3").fadeIn("slow");
    });
  }

  // $(".activebox").fadeOut("fast", function(){
  //  $("#klk-map-content-1").fadeIn("slow");
  //  $("#klk-map-content-2").fadeIn("slow");
  //  $("#klk-map-content-3").fadeIn("slow");
  // });

  function getCoords(position) {
    var text = position.replace(/[()]/g, '').split(", ");
    var lat = Number(text[0]);
    var lng = Number(text[1]);

    return {
      lat: lat,
      lng: lng
    };
  }


}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map-canvas {
  height: 85%;
  width: 100%;
}

#overlay {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#active {
  background-color: #333;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 25.00%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}

.nav {
  display: table;
  height: 15%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav li {
  border-left: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
  color: #787878;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table-cell;
  font-family: 'Sanchez', serif;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 25%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.nav li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <!-- Link -->
  <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sanchez">
</head>


<body>
  <!-- Content -->
  <div id="map-canvas" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;"></div>


  <div id="overlay" class="activebox" style="display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 1000; background-color: white; top: 50px; left: 10px; height: auto; width: 300px; overflow: auto; border-top: 5px green solid; padding: 1rem;">
    <div class="klk-map-contents" id="klk-map-content-1">Content 1</div>
    <div class="klk-map-contents" id="klk-map-content-2" style="display: none;">Content 2</div>
    <div class="klk-map-contents" id="klk-map-content-3" style="display: none;">Content 3</div>
  </div>


  <!-- Script CDN -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>



  <!-- Script -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You registered only 2 marker click event listeners so how do you expect the other markers to do anything? Further to that, you should learn some basics of Javascript because creating one separate function for every marker on your map is most likely not the way to go...

Comment: Check [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56869829/google-maps-multiple-markers-with-unique-infowindows) for a related example. You should replace the InfoWindow stuff with your jQuery fadeOut/In functions.